# How to Retrieve the Remote desktop connection active users details

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, telnet

There is a Multiple server used the company, everyone in the team can connect to this server using the remote desktop connection.

I want the code to get the active username(system name) and status who connected to the server.

code written by c# Asp.net core 7  Web api application used mysql database code and using telnet.
How to checks the current user RDP status and whether the user active or not

How to used the Telnet in asp.net core 7 WebApi Application to retrieve the Remote desktop connection active user detail.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/query-user